# Labels package: \LeftBorder, etc., not defined

Tags: pdftex, sticky-labels

I am trying to use the "labels" package with the following code, which should, as far as I understand the documentation, work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}

\begin{document}

\begin{labels}
\LabelCols=3%         Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=7%         Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftBorder=8mm%      Space added to left border of each label
\RightBorder=8mm%     Space added to right border of each label
\TopBorder=9mm%       Space to leave at top of sheet
\BottomBorder=2mm%    Space to leave at bottom of sheet


  bla
  blubb


  quiek
  nilpferd
\end{labels}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the error messages that `LeftBorder`, `RightBorder`, `TopBorder` and `BottomBorder` are undefined control sequences. `LabelCols` and `LabelRows` are defined however, so the package should be found.

`pdflatex -v` says `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/NixOS.org)`; not sure how to find out what version of labels is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either drop `newdimen` option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{labels}

\begin{document}

    \begin{labels}
        \LabelCols=3%         Number of columns of labels per page
        \LabelRows=7%         Number of rows of labels per page
        \LeftBorder=8mm%      Space added to left border of each label
        \RightBorder=8mm%     Space added to right border of each label
        \TopBorder=9mm%       Space to leave at top of sheet
        \BottomBorder=2mm%    Space to leave at bottom of sheet
        \LabelSetup


        bla
        blubb


        quiek
        nilpferd
    \end{labels}

\end{document}
```

Or use the appropriate parameters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}


\begin{document}
    \begin{labels}

\LabelCols=3% Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=7% Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftPageMargin=7mm% These four parameters give the
\RightPageMargin=7mm% page gutter sizes. The outer edges of
\TopPageMargin=15mm% the outer labels are the specified
\BottomPageMargin=15mm% distances from the edge of the paper.
\InterLabelColumn=2mm% Gap between columns of labels

\InterLabelRow=0mm% Gap between rows of labels
\LeftLabelBorder=5mm% These four parameters give the extra
\RightLabelBorder=5mm% space used around the text on each
\TopLabelBorder=5mm% actual label.
\BottomLabelBorder=5mm%

        \LabelSetup


        bla
        blubb


        quiek
        nilpferd
    \end{labels}

\end{document}
```

Both cases, you should call `\LabelSetup` if you specify the parameters after `\begin{document}`. If you specify them before, you don't have to add `\LabelSetup`.

(Source: pages 3-4 of the [documentation](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/labels/labels.pdf))